# Redshift: Behaviour when disk is full?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a multi-node redshift cluster and noticed this behavior. A given query with given date range used to return me a specific number of rows, say - `X`. In the last few days, the cluster disk got filled upto `99.75%`. Data loads were still succesful but the same query returned me `Y` number of rows with `Y<X`. *So it looks like Redhsift removed some random rows(I have reasons to believe its random)*

Now I resized the cluster and ran the same query to again get `X` number of rows. I made this hypothesis that:-

> Under low disk, Redshift will archive some random rows(S3?) to keep the availability and restore data accordingly when the disk space is available.

However I am unable to find any official documentation for this behavior with disk space thresholds for archiving at restoring (It didn't restored at 90%, but at 65% when I added a new node). Could anybody point me to the correct document or confirm this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. I contacted Amazon on the forums, where I was later contacted by one of the product manager of redshift on personal chat. They are able to reproduce the bug with interleaved keys, were a `VACUUM REINDEX` operation can corrupt the indices, giving wrong answer to `count` queries. Amazon gave me two solutions:-

1. After corruption, perform a deep copy of the table and run `VACUUM REINDEX` again.
2. Switch to composite keys.

Option 1, is clearly very taxing for both resources and manpower. We switched to composite keys, which is again not the perfect solution for us, but working. Last update was 2 weeks back. Follow the discussion here:-  [Vacuum reindex causing wrong data counts in the table](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=799197#799197).

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Redshift would not remove any data.

You should always aim to keep spare storage capacity on the cluster to provide adequate space for `VACUUM` operations and for complex queries.

Clusters actually have more disk space than publicly shown, but this extra capacity should not be relied upon.

You should consult the [`STL_LOAD_ERRORS`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html) table to see whether any errors occurred during your load that resulted in fewer rows being loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We however have a cron which run vacuum after checking the sorting state of the table. Also there is no erors in STL_LOAD_ERRORS as I mentioned earlier. It is just that we had so much data loaded into the Redshift suddenly due to a some new clients.

Comment: I am also not able to find anthing in particular to this use case when al the disk is full when you can't even run Vacuum or complex queries.

Comment: it was a bug in Redshift. See my answer. You were right, the data wasn't removed